# Facebook : How can i use access token to tag a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Below code uploads the photo successfully, but when I try to tag I get the following error:

> Uncaught OAuthException: Invalid OAuth access token signature

How can I use accesstoken to tag a photo?

```
$photo = $facebook->api('/'.$aid.'/photos', 'POST', $attachment);


$tags['access_token'] = $access_token;
$tags = array(
  'tag_uid'=> $re[0],
  'x'      => '30',
  'y'      => '60',
);
$response = $facebook->api('/'.$photo['id'].'/tags', 'POST', $tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the "to" argument

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/#tags

```
 $tags['access_token'] = $access_token;
 $tags = array(
 'to' => $user,
 'tag_uid'=> $re[0],
 'x'      => '30',
 'y'      => '60',
);
$response = $facebook->api('/'.$photo['id'].'/tags', 'POST', $tags);
```